# What is the name of the species of this butterfly?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

Well,I am from India and live in the northern part of the country.I commonly find these butterflies during winter or spring seasons.
[image]

The original image shot is:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! What size is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but it looks like a male "common mormon" or *Papilio polytes romulus*
 [image]
https://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Papilio_polytes_romulus

Comment: The image of the species on the left looks quite identical and accurate.And also,it’s written on Wikipedia that the species is found in Nepal which is the country lying just above the border our state.Thanks.

Comment: Those two butterflies are the same species.  The one on the left is a male.  The one on the right is the female.